# Does a linker generate final virtual memory addresses with no-pie flag?

Tags: c, linker, virtual-memory

Assume we compile this code with `gcc -no-pie test.c`.
ASLR is now disabled.

**test.c**

```
int main(){
 int a = 5;
 return a;
}
```

The allocated initial memory addresses of `main` can be seen using `objdump`:

```
0000000000401106 <main>:
  401106:   f3 0f 1e fa             endbr64
```

Using gdb, I can see the same address at runtime after it's loaded:

```
(gdb)  b main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x401106
```

Is it safe to say, when executable is not `position independent` then the addresses
generated during link time are final virtual memory addresses? if binary is moved to another host with the same OS it will be loaded at the same virtual address?

Comment: Nitpick: *"ASLR is now disabled"* - ASLR is still enabled. The no-pie flag merely creates an ELF Executable instead of an ELF Shared Object, and the kernel will then load the executable at the virtual address it expects to be loaded at, without applying ASLR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it safe to say, when executable is not position independent then the addresses generated during link time are final virtual memory addresses?

Yes.

> if binary is moved to another host with the same OS it will be loaded at the same virtual address?

Yes.

The non-PIE binary linked at a specific address will run correctly *only* if it is loaded at the linked-at address. Loading it at any other address will cause it to crash.